# How to receive the entire object of req.body.model instead of all variables of it separately in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I  have an example form with two elements, name and surname from model user

```
form(action="/user/create", method="post")
    label(for="name") Name
    input(type="text", id="name", name="name", value="", autofocus)

    label(for="surname") Surname
    input(type="text", id="surname", name="surname", value="")
```

When I'm posting it I send an object in the request body

```
{
    "name": "[value input name]", 
    "surname": "[value input surname]"
}
```

For this reason, in my node js server I get this model values for validate it with this:

```
{
    name: req.body.name,
    surname: req.body.surname
}
```

But I want to get all model info as object

```
form(action="/user/create", method="post")
    label(for="name") Name
    input(type="text", id="name", name="user.name", value="", autofocus)
    br
    label(for="surname") Surname
    input(type="text", id="surname", name="user.surname", value="")
```

And get it as:

```
req.body.user
```

But it returns me undefined. When I read req.body is:

```
{
    "user.name": "[value input name]",
    "user.username": "[value input surname]"
}
```

I want to get something as:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name":"[value input name]",
        "surname":"[value input surname]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
input#name(type="text", name="user[name]", value="", autofocus)
input#surname(type="text", name="user[surname]", value="")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11957454)

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan: why do you think my post does not provide an answer?

Comment: Do remember to add an explanation instead of simply posting chunks of code.

Comment: @Huey: I usually do, but in this case that's just the way it's done - no idea what to explain about it.